# facebook logout without sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

How can I log out user from facebook without authorizing him myself?

I have a public IPad which people come to, authorize in my application and do stuff.
One of the links leads to m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=..
When the user presses it, he is redirected to facebook, which asks for his login/pass and makes the share.

Later then the user press Logout **on my site**
I need to log out him from facebook some way,
so the next user who will use the ipad and press share will post to his wall and not to the first user's .

Same happens when i provide the iframe version of the Like button.
The first user logs in to facebook, makes the *like*, logs out of my web site,
and the next user see the like button pressed.

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just done some work with facebook recently on one of my projects and I used to visit a url to log them out it was something like

http://www.facebook.com/logout.php?redirect=your_url

It may not exactly be that as its off the top off my head but after visiting that the user got redirected to my site again logged out of facebook.

You may also have to provide a token.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a token, and without it the logout page just leaves the user logged in, redirectng him to his wall.

Comment: I've just got back into work now and checked my code and it does seem to be that you have to have a valid access token in order to do it.

Comment: To acquire the token you have to be the one who authorized the user via FB.Login(), but it's not me who authorized him, therefore I don't have any token to provide.

Comment: Unfortunately without that access token you wont be able to make calls like that on behalf of the user, for obvious reasons. Sorry I cant help :(